# Seeing PHP code instead of install on Mac localhost using MAMP

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, osx-mavericks, mamp

iMac running Mavericks (10.9.5)

MAMP server (Version 3.2.1)

Installed MAMP about 2 months ago changed default root folder from 8888 (Applications folder/MAMP/ht_docs) to the *Sites* folder on my iMac. Installed WordPress and built a website. Deleted website and built another one.

When I tried to install WordPress the second time was only seeing the PHP raw page code and not the install page. I worked around this by altering the files but can't really remember what I did. Site was built and all running fine.

I learned now that I can have more than one WP site running on my iMac so have gone through the creation process (new database etc…) but once again am faced with the raw PHP code instead of the install.php.!

Can someone help me? I want to install through the WP  installer page as normal.

PHP is ok as I have another site running from the *Sites* folder.

Comment: Can you show us the php code you are getting? Maybe you did not start the servers?!

Comment: Just to rule that out, you're using `http://` and not `file://`, right?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I hadn't set as http it was file. Thank you so much for that Siguza. All working fine now :)